# How to use trained neural network to predict future values of time series?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have been using neural network toolbox (MATLAB) for time series prediction. I have followed every step given in the help manual and finally I have got a "net" network.

My input had 1344 values, but the output has 1340 values (because of the delay was 4). But my question is that how do I know the 1341th value and so on using the trained neural network?

Comment: I believe you want a NN that takes `t` and gives you a single value as output.....

Comment: yeah..it is a time series of energy demand of a country. any ideas, how can I get a output value that takes t?

Comment: You need to train your NN so it takes 1 input and gives 1 output.

Comment: you need to understand that an ANN is generally used for Classification rather than Prediction, prediction of time series can easily be done using regression, interpolation techniques, or if you want to be fancy, machine learnt model approaches such as GMM HMM NMF etc are better choices than ANN. WHY? Because the ANN is a network it trains on different patterns, and recognize the patterns and outputs whatever your ANN structure design wants it to output.

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
net = newff(observations,targets,10);
[net,tr] = train(net,observations',targets');
erg = zeros(size(test_mat,1),1);
for i = 1: size(test_mat,1)
    y = sim(net,test_mat(i,:)');
    erg(i)=find(compet(y));
end
```

where `observations` is your training set `targets` are the known values of the hindcast and `test_mat` are the values for the forecast. In `erg` the predictions for the forecast are stored.